# What are addition properties of polynomial ring?

Tags: ring-theory

If set $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is set of all polynomials with integer coefficients.

Every polynom $f\in \mathbb{Z}\left [ x \right ]$ can be written as $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i , $ $ a_i\in \mathbb{Z} $and $n\in \mathbb{N}.$

$\mathbb{Z}\left [ x \right ]$ with the usual addition and multiplication of polynomials is one ring.

**What are addition properties of polynomial ring?**

Comment: If and only if $K$ is a field, then $K[x]$ is a [principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain#Examples).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
The text states that $\Z [x]$ with the usual operations is a ring, so the addition is associative and commutative, there is an element $0\in \Z [x]$ such that $p+0=p$ $\forall p \in \Z[x]$, and every element $p\in \Z [x]$ has an additive inverse (given by $-p$). These are the principal addition properties in $\Z [x]$.